# Is it correct to say "the passion has intensified"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In a context as follows:

> A passion in science and technology, which has considerably
>   intensified by gaining more knowledge in physics and electronics,
>   continuously motivates me to take up engineering.

Is it correct to say the passion has intensified?

Comment: You should clarify your question by pointing out the reason why it seems problematic to you.

Comment: Intensify is transitive (intensify something) and needs a complement. You may use instead grown, escalated, heightened, deepened, strengthened, reinforced, ...

Answer (score 1):

*A passion has intensified* is not ungrammatical (see reference below), but is inelegant. In addition, the sentence has several other rough edges grammar-wise. You might want to rephrase it. Consider:

> **My** passion **for** science and technology, which **grew** considerably
> **stronger** through **a deeper knowledge** in physics and electronics, is what motivates me to take up engineering.

*To intensify* can be intransitive:

> v. intr. To become intense or more intense:
>
> *The search intensified as
> dusk approached*.

(AHD)

Comment: You are perfectly right, using "intensifiy" intransitively is correct. But, in the OP sentence, it didn't really sound natural in OP sentence.

Comment: No, it didn't, no argument there.